# Xcode 13.2 “Second Editor”

Tags: xcode13, xcode13.2

I have Xcode configured so that <kbd>option</kbd>-click on a file will open it in the “second” editor.

[image]

This worked in Xcode 13.0 and earlier, but in Xcode 13.2.1 (13C100), I cannot get it to use the second editor at all. Before I file a bug report, are others having the same problem and has anyone discovered a work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new “focus editor” button next to file selector. When it is blue, the secondary editor is disabled (only allows assistant).

When it is white, you can open secondary editors.

Horrible UX and has caused me hours of headache.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I went back to my backup of the `xcuserdatad` folder and this was indeed the problem. Wow, what a weird and incomprehensible feature. I don't see what problem they were trying to solve here, but it certainly could have been implemented better...

Comment: For those looking for this “Focus this Editor” button, it only appears once you have a second editor visible (and once you tap this button, you only have the focused editor visible until you tap the “Unfocus this Editor” button). I wish that once you did something to open something in the second editor again, that it would automatically disable this “focus” mode.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me in Xcode 13.2.1, so I can't reproduce the issue. Maybe download that before filing a bug?

[image]

(Also, make sure nothing has gone wrong with your keyboard's Option key; yes, I've had problems with that in the past.)

By the way, my favored setting (though not what I used while testing your report, of course) is to have Optional Navigation set to Uses Destination Chooser; it gives so much flexibility as to where the file will be edited!

Comment: Actually, I am using 13.2.1. And I downloaded Xcode 13.0 and confirmed that it works there. I tried “Uses Destination Choose” and that doesn't work, either. Hmm.

Comment: I added a little animated screencast thingy to show what Option-click does on my machine. I'm serious about the possibility that you've disabled your Option key somehow; my keyboard has a "secret handshake" that makes it easy to do that by mistake.

Comment: Oh but then I guess it wouldn't work in 13.0, eh. :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing additional experimentation, it appears that the problem is unique to a particular project. If I create a new project, the UI works as expected.

I fixed the problem by:

- exiting Xcode;
- removing the `.xcuserdatad` folder within the `.xcodeproj` package; and
- restarting Xcode.

Comment: Too weird. How can a project disable Option navigation???? Oh Xcode.

Comment: No way I can do this. Too many custom configs

Comment: Lol. Out of curiosity, what custom configs are you doing that are stored in `.xcuserdatad` (besides breakpoints)? Frankly, I’m just thrilled I didn’t have to entirely recreate the project from scratch, losing all of my targets, schemes, build settings, etc. I am relieved to get away with just losing user data…